# Is it possible to add type hints to an object whose attributes are defined on instantiation?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to define a class whose attributes are (mostly) provided by its users on instantiation. (There's more functionality to it, but this is what matters for the question.) My approach so far has been to pass keyword arguments to `__init__` and then these kwargs are transformed into attributes (pretty much the same as  `argparse.Namespace`).

It can be boiled down to this:

```
class Bag:
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        vars(self).update(kwargs)
```

And then it's used like this:

```
b = Bag(a=some_function, b=2)
```

This works as expected, the problem is that IDEs have no chance to provide autocomplete suggestions and that makes it less comfortable to use.

The question is if it's possible to somehow propagate the types of the passed arguments to the `Bag` instance itself (obviously only when this call can be analyzed statically). Or, if there's a more elegant alternative.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:**

A hacky alternative I came up with was to use a class declaration with a metaclass to provide my extra functionality, and then use the class as if it was an object. Something like this:

```
class some_bag(metaclass=MagicBag):
    a = "hello"
    b = 2

some_bag.a  # <-- recognized by the IDE
```

(This has however its own share of problems)

Comment: No, you cannot. Not at least in any way that a static analysis tool would understand, at least none I've encountered.

Comment: And note, all attributes are defined on instantiation. That's how Python works. The point of type hints are to give *static analysis tools* information. But you want to give the static analysis tools information that is dynamically generated, this is a bit like trying to have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: "so far I could get it to work with a metaclass, but overall the solution was even less ergonomic" what does that mean exactly? You were able to get your IDE to recognize it using a metaclass?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the metaclass approach kind of works, but requires some mental gymnastics. This way: the user defines a class with the desired members AND uses my metaclass (which attaches the features I need), and then the class is used as if it were a normal object instance.

Comment: _Static type checkers do not execute your code, they just read it._ If you want this kind of IDE magic, you'll have to write your own plugin for it.

Comment: @bgusach sorry, that didn't really answer my question. Was the static analysis tooling able to recognize the dynamically created attributes with your metaclass approach? Can you elaborate in the quesiton itself?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg indeed. But if they can read and understand `self.name = name` (thus providing useful type hints), maybe they could also read `vars(self).update(kwargs)` and infer the attributes from static calls. Admittedly, this is orders of magnitude more complicated.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I elaborated my question with the metaclass approach. It may be very anticlimactic ;)

Comment: @bgusach aaaaah I see. You are using the class directly as the bag.

Comment: Anyway, yeah, in theory, the static analysis could understand something like `vars(self).update(x='foo', y='bar')` but I don't think any do (it would generally have to be a special case)

Comment: What are the issues you're having with the metaclass approach?